# redirect ID numbers to sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

www.mydomain.com/1233.html   this is the main topic  which we have in the website and i need  remove my script from this site and who ever will enter this link will be redirected to the link below

myprogram.mydomain.com/v2/1233.html

what is the process on doing so and the setup required for the file below ?
.htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The following should be put in your document root. Uncomment the first line if you want it to match www.example.com only, and not example.com or myprogram.example.com

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(\d+\.html)$ http://myprogram.example.com/v2/$1 [L]
```